# Swift enumeration is being treated as optional?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, option-type

On the line below in the 'CardDeck' class that looks like this

```
let card = CardSprite(value: i, withSuite: suit)
```

I get the error:

```
Value of optional type 'Suit?' not unwrapped. Did you mean to use "!" or "?"
```

I did not expect this error based on my understanding of the constructs being used. Does anyone know why the enumeration type Suit is considered optional in this example? I'm using Xcode 7 beta 4.
Note: I can follow the instructions that XCode pops up to fix this. I just don't understand why this is happening. XCode is recommending explicit unwrap like this

```
let card = CardSprite(value: i, withSuite: suit!)
```

Thanks
Mike

this is some code:

```
enum Suit: Int
{
    case None=0,
    Spade,
    Club,
    Hearts,
    Diamonds
}
class CardSprite : SKSpriteNode
{
    var m_value: Int
    var m_suite: Suit

    init(value:Int, withSuite suite: Suit)
    {
        m_value = value
        m_suite = suite
        super.init(texture:nil, color:UIColor.redColor(), size:CGSize(width:20, height:50))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        m_value = -1
        m_suite = Suit.None
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
class CardDeck
{
    var cards: [CardSprite]
    init ()
    {
        cards = [CardSprite]()
        for s in 1...4{
            let suit = Suit(rawValue:s)

            for i in 1...13{
                let card = CardSprite(value: i, withSuite: suit)
                cards.append(card)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The initializer taking a rawValue returns an optional, to account for a value not mapped by a enum case. If you are sure the raw value is good, force unwrap it, but I'd recommend an optional binding instead

Answer (score 4):

`let suit = Suit(rawValue:s)` is an optional. Creating an Enum from a raw value always returns an optional. However, seeing as you have a None case you can override this behavior by overriding the raw value initializer.

```
enum Suit: Int
{
    case None=0,
    Spade,
    Club,
    Hearts,
    Diamonds

    init(rawValue: Int) {
        switch rawValue {
        case Suit.Spade.rawValue:
            self = Suit.Spade
        case Suit.Club.rawValue:
            self = Suit.Club
        case Suit.Hearts.rawValue:
            self = Suit.Hearts
        case Suit.Diamonds.rawValue:
            self = Suit.Diamonds
        default:
            self = Suit.None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK that totally makes sense. I went back and re-read the Enumeration documentation and now I see that I missed that discussion on rawValue. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, and I would appreciate you accepting this answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

Don't iterate over `1...4` to create `Suit` from its raw value - iterate over the `Suits` directly:

Something like such:

```
for suit in [.Spades, .Clubs, .Hearts, .Diamonds] { ... }
```

Additionally, dump the `.None` case as there is no such `Suit`.  Also, check your plurality - all the suits should be plural - `.Spade` -> `.Spades`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not working with the raw value.
Try something like this:

```
enum Suit {
  case None
  case Spade(_:Int)
  case Club(_:Int)
  case Hearts(_:Int)
  case Diamonds(_:Int)
}

func trythis(suit: Suit) {
  switch (suit) {
  case .Club(let value):
    print("value \(value)")
  case .Hearts(let value):
    print("value \(value)")
  case .Spade(let value):
    print("value \(value)")
  case .Diamonds(let value):
      print("value \(value)")
  case .None:
    print("nothing to see here")
  }
}
```

And you can call the function like this:

```
trythis(.Club(4))
```

You can attach these to your CardSprite to determine its color and value this way.